integral of $\int_0^\infty \frac{2y^n}{e^{2y} - 1} dy$
I'm reading the David Tong's notes (p.111) from Cambridge and I'm facing an integral which I don't know how the author solve it.
$$\int_0^\infty  \frac{2y^n}{e^{2y} - 1} dy = \frac{I_n}{2^n}$$
$$I_n = \int  \frac{y^n}{e^y-1} dy$$
It might be trivial, but I don't see how the first integral becomes essentially:
$$\frac{1}{2^n} \int  \frac{y^n}{e^y-1} dy$$

Do you mean $(2y)^n$, not $2y^n$?  Use parentheses to make your intentions clear. Also, you write $e^2 - 1$ rather than $e^y - 1$.

@amWhy Ok, I removed it. I do not think however that this is a duplicate. As I mentioned below the question is simply about the process of transforming the initial integral to $I_n/2^n$ and not about the evaluation of $I_n$ itself.

@KCd I fixed $e^2$. however, it is $2y^n$ and not $(2y)^2$.
Also, this post is not a duplicate. Since As Gary says I'm not interested about the evaluation of $I_n$.

In the original integral, perform the change of variables from $y$ to $t$ by $t=2y$. What do you get?

Exactly. I saw my mistake at the same moment you wrote the solution.
It was not that hard, but I couldn't find it by myself sadly.
Thank you!
